# Who viewed my SPO page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

I've recently created a page in SharePoint for survey . The page has 800 views till now . Is there any way to see who viewed it . I tried audit feature but it no longer supports SharePoint. Is there any way to get it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use default audit feature to achieve it.

Go to the site settings-> Site Collection Administration->Audit log reports->content viewing->save the report->download the report->open the report->click “Report data 1” sheet->click document Location->search your page URL->then you can see who view the page.

[image]

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[How to Generate a Page View Report in SharePoint Online.](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2014/09/21/page-views-in-0365-sharepoint-online)